# Python/Pandas - Combine two columns with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say i have a dataframe with two columns: OldValue and NewValue

i want to do some plotting and i want to combine values. If OldValue is empty, NewValue is filled, and the other way around. There is not a single instance both or neither are filled.
Lets say my dataframe looks like this:

```
  OldValue NewValue
0  14.0     NaN 
1  NaN     7.0
2  3.0     NaN
3  NaN     3.0
```

I found that i could fillna(0) and then do something along the lines of

```
df["AllValue"] = df["NewValue"] + df["OldValue"]
```

Is this the most efficient way?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72164923/7066658

Answer (score 4):

Your solution should be change with [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) and `fill_value=0`:

```
df["AllValues"] = df["Newvalues"].add(df["OldValues"], fill_value=0)
```

Or use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df["AllValue"] = df["NewValue"].fillna(df["OldValue"])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
df["AllValue"] = df["OldValue"]  # make a copy
df.loc[df["AllValue"].isna(), "AllValue"] = df.loc[~df["NewValue"].isna(), "NewValue"]
```